# Delphi выдает ошибку, что не найдены файлы/библиотеки типа "Vcl.Forms.dcu"

Tags: delphi, библиотеки, delphi-xe2

Программа была написана другим человеком на другом компьютере, а мне нужно теперь ее отлаживать, но я не могу скомпилировать измененный код, так как выдает ошибки, насколько я понял, нехватки библиотек.

К примеру пишет нет файла Vcl.Forms.dcu, а когда его скачал и скинул в папку с библиотеками пишет что не может найти файл Vcl.Forms.pas. Так же там подключены такие модули: `Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, StdCtrls, Controls,  Classes;`.

Вроде бы это стандартные библиотеки. Что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить эти ошибки?

Comment: До точки это неймспейсы, которые придумали только в XE2, если убрать - заработает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VCL - это базовая библиотека визуальных компонентов, и все, что с ней связано, уже есть в Delphi, и качать это не надо.

Компилятор может ругаться на указание "VCL" перед классом. Попробуйте написать просто:

```
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, StdCtrls, Controls, Classes;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло. Делал сам так уже, но все равно выдавало ошибку и не мог понять, почему и лишь когда вы написали обратил внимание:

>Если убрать указания типа Vcl то получится что 3 класса (`StdCtrls, Controls, Classes`) используются дважды. 

В этом и была ошибка.